# Estimator with numpy array input_fn

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am creating an estimator with numpy array to feed to model with using `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn`. Like the following:

```
def input_fun(data):
    x, y = data

    x, y = np.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, 1)), \
           np.reshape(y, (batch_size, -1, 1))

    return tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'x': x}, y)

def forward(x, params, mode):

    layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_neurons) for _ in range(n_layers)]
    cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(layers)
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, x)

    predictions = ...

    return predictions

def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    predict = forward(features, params, mode)

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(predict , ...)

def experiment_fn(config, params):
    return learn.Experiment(
        estimator = estimator(model_fn,...),
        train_input_fn = lambda: input_fun(train_set),
        eval_input_fn = lambda: input_fun(eval_set))
```

It throws the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Experiment.py',
>   wdir='/TensorFlow')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Experiment.py", line 490, in 
>       hparams = params
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_runner.py",
>   line 218, in run
>       return _execute_schedule(experiment, schedule)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\learn_runner.py",
>   line 46, in _execute_schedule
>       return task()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py",
>   line 367, in train
>       hooks=self._train_monitors + extra_hooks)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\learn\python\learn\experiment.py",
>   line 807, in _call_train
>       hooks=hooks)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 302, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 711, in _train_model
>       features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 694, in _call_model_fn
>       model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Experiment.py", line 350, in model_fn
>       predict = forward(features, params, mode)
>
> File "/Experiment.py", line 335, in forward
>       dtype = tf.float32
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py",
>   line 562, in dynamic_rnn
>       flat_input = [ops.convert_to_tensor(input_) for input_ in flat_input]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\rnn.py",
>   line 562, in 
>       flat_input = [ops.convert_to_tensor(input_) for input_ in flat_input]
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 836, in convert_to_tensor
>       as_ref=False)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 926, in internal_convert_to_tensor
>       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
>       return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py",
>   line 208, in constant
>       value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py",
>   line 472, in make_tensor_proto
>       "supported type." % (type(values), values))
>
> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'function'> to
>   Tensor. Contents: <function numpy_input_fn.<locals>.input_fn at
>   0x000001AB2B1DBEA0>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: It is outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, x)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case the exception was raised because inside my model (I guess "forward", in your case) x was used as a Tensor, but it was actually a function (specifically tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn).
I figured it out by adding this:

```
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

Which printed something like this:

```
<function numpy_input_fn.<locals>.input_fn at 0x7fcc6f065740>
<class 'function'>
```

I'm still not sure what is the correct way to solve it, but I was able to fix it by doing something similar to this:

```
input_dict, y = x()
x = input_dict['x']
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a list of cells into [`MultiRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell):

> Args:
>
> **`cells`**: list of RNNCells that will be composed in this order.
>
> **`state_is_tuple`**: If True, accepted and returned states are n-tuples,
>   where `n = len(cells)`. If False, the states are all concatenated along
>   the column axis. This latter behavior will soon be deprecated.

If you really want to make a one-layer RNN, change the code to

```
cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([layers])
```

... or create more layers.

Comment: Sorry, I trimmed the code to look less complicated but it was a list. I updated the code. Still I have the same error.

Comment: The error is not in your snippet. Show us the full code

Comment: When I run the outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells,x) I have the error. I updated to show the full traceback. You see it comes from the dynamic_rnn. It's a problem with the way I employ the numpy_input_fn.